# Check if your python code is running in the background on EC2

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2

I ran a python code on EC2 ubutuntu server, and then closed my laptop, so the ssh into my EC2 stopped. I want to check now if the python code has finished running on the cluster.
So I ssh-ed into the cluster and typed the below command: I got the following output.
Does this mean that the code has finished running?

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~$ ps ax | grep python3
  760 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
  826 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
21408 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto python3
```

I also checked for the actual file:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~$ ps ax | grep run_file.py 
21406 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto run_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a Linux / BASH question than a python question.

More than likely your script stopped executing when you closed your SSH session.  You need to run the script in tmux, screen, or using the nohup command so when you exit your session the script keeps running.

I prefer `screen` but you need to install it if it's not already installed.  Same with `tmux`.  `nohup` should be available in most Linux installs.

```
nohup python script.py &
```

`man nohup` for more information

Comment: thank you. I will use that next time. and have updated the tags!